# `./configure` options for cross compile?

Tags: autoconf, configure, cross-compiling

As far as I know, `./configure` script is generated with GNU `Autoconf`. I don't know about `Autoconf` at all. How do these tools work, and how can I use this `./configure` script to make source to cross-compile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine host value for configure when using cross compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990021/how-to-determine-host-value-for-configure-when-using-cross-compiler)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pretty good little article to read on how to cross-compile: http://linux.bytesex.org/cross-compiler.html.

The main part in cross-compiling is setting the configure flags for the compiler to poinst to the target architecture and platform:

```
./configure --target=sparc-linux --with-gnu-as i486-redhat-linux
```

This might be outdated (modified copy & paste from that article), but the same concept still applies.