# Compiling x264 for i386

Tags: c++, c, cross-compiling, x264, i386

How would I compile the x264 library for the i386 architecture? Usually to force an architecture I would use the follow command:

```
./configure CC="gcc -arch i386" CXX="g++ -arch i386"
```

But it doesn't seem to work for x264.

To compile x264 I configure it and make it, this produces an x86_64 library. When I attempt to use the above command to force the i386 architecture I receive the following message:

> Unknown option CC=gcc -arch i386, ignored Unknown option CXX=g++ -arch i386, ignored

The configure script then prints that it is configured for the X86_64 platform. I want to see it configured for the i386 platform and to produce an i386 binary.

Comment: Define "it doesn't seem to work".

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What do you see instead?

Comment: To compile x264 I configure it and make it, this produces an x86_64 library. When I attempt to use the above command to force the i386 architecture I receive the following message:
Unknown option CC=gcc -arch i386, ignored
Unknown option CXX=g++ -arch i386, ignored
The configure script then prints that it is configured for the X86_64 platform. I want to see it configured for the i386 platform and to produce an i386 binary.

Comment: Have you tried `./configure --help`? x264 does not use plain autotools if I remember correctly.

Comment: I have, it isn't helpful with regarding cross compiling, it says there is a --host parameter but I do not know the host I need to enter for i386

Answer (score 5):

Autotooled `configure` scripts have special command-line arguments `--build` and `--host` that they use to configure cross-compilation. Some old configure scripts attempt to figure out they are cross-compiling by inspecting the output of the compiler, but telling the configure script explicitly is much saner and more robust.

See [here](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/autoconf/Hosts-and-Cross_002dCompilation.html), for example. Or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139247/configure-options-for-cross-compile).

*(Oh, and the immediate reason for the "Unknown option" errors you're seeing is that environment-variable overrides go **before** the name of the script on the sh command line, not after it. It's not `make`, where variable definitions can be given on the make command line itself.)*

Comment: configure has been taking options this way for a long time now.

Comment: Oh. Well, apparently the one the OP is using doesn't. (I'm extrapolating its behavior from the wording of the error messages he quoted).

Comment: Yes, you're right. And not all configure scripts are autoconf anyway.

Comment: So if I use ./configure --host=i386-apple-darwin10 it says "no working C Compiler found", is there any way to print a list of valid hosts?

Answer (score 4):

After reading the configure script and config.sub file, I found the following to work for building a i386 version of libx264:

```
./configure --host=i386-apple-darwin
```

I also encountered that "no working C Compiler found" error at one point. I had set the LDFLAGS environment variable to something wrong. So make sure LDFLAGS and CFLAGS are empty (or good) before proceeding.

```
export CFLAGS=""
export LDFLAGS=""
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an x86-64 gcc you can supply the "-m32" to ask it to compile a 32-bit binary. So you should be able to use configure like this:

```
./configure CFLAGS="-m32"
```

If however that doesn't work it may be a bug in the autotooling and the CFLAGS are getting overwritten. An alternative you can try:

```
make CFLAGS="-m32"
```

The problem with the latter is that you have to remember to do this, otherwise you'll end up with linking issues with some object files built for different architectures.

Comment: You may also need LDFLAGS="-m32" to get the linking done right.

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple's recommendations at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/compiling/compiling.html
try:

```
./configure
make CFLAGS="-arch i386" LDFLAGS="-arch i386"
```

If that doesn't work add the -isysroot flags as well (but 10.6 or 10.7 rather than 10.4u)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, it just throws up a lot of errors