# How to create a binary executable for 32 bit gcc machine from my 64 bit gcc machine?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I want to create binary executable of my source code to run on 32 bit gcc machine. But I have 64 bit gcc installed. Is there any way to create a binary executable for 32 bit gcc machines from my 64 bit gcc??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My machine is  **ELF 64-bit LSB**  by default if u compile it will produce you 64 bit executable.

```
 gcc  hello.c -o hello
```

use **file** to check it

```
 hello: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=9f8fa8ac13fc03672306da1d5d4ee6671114eb11, not stripped
```

Use flag -m32 then you forcing your compiler for 32 bit

```
  gcc -m32 hello.c -o hello

 file hello
 hello : ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=c72216023939b2832467c624850f164d1857e645, not stripped
```

If you looking for cross-compiling This might help u [How to determine host value for configure when using cross compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990021/how-to-determine-host-value-for-configure-when-using-cross-compiler/21992287#21992287)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make GCC use the -m32 flag.

You could try writing a simple shell script to your $PATH and call it gcc (make sure you don't overwrite the original gcc, and make sure the new script comes earlier in $PATH, and that it uses the full path to GCC.

compile your binary like -:

```
/bin/gcc -m32 "source file"
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining it in a bit clear way

Comment: @Nazeem I think you are asking about shell script line, Here i mean if you have gcc compiler for 32 bit then you can compile your program with that like a cross compiler. Hope you got my point.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2010-09/msg00040.html this link could help you.