# How to determine the architecture of my machine to give to configure's `--host` option

Tags: cross-platform, configure

Many questions gives [hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990021/how-to-determine-host-value-for-configure-when-using-cross-compiler) about the `--host`, `--build` and `--target` options of configure. While i understand what is the purpose of these options, i would like to know how to find the triplet to provide to these options.

I have found across the web may examples of values, like `arm-none-linux-gnueabi`, `mac`, `x86`, and `arm`.

Is there a command-line utility that is able to return this value, knowing the machine on which it is runned ?
Or even an unofficial-but-generally-working algorithm that allow one to build the triplet, knowing basic informations about involved machines ?
Or maybe a list of all known triplets i can try until one produce a binary that can run on the host machine ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine host value for configure when using cross compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990021/how-to-determine-host-value-for-configure-when-using-cross-compiler)

Comment: Since the question already links to that supposedly duplicate, and do not answers this question, the duplicate mark seems dubious.