# how to compile libuv for armeabi-v7a, armeabi-v8a, MIPS arm architectures?

Tags: libuv

I want to use libuv as a library for my project, (i.e) libuv.a. I compiled for arm64/arm32 architectures. I need to compile for armeabi-v7a,armeabi-v8a, MIPs architectures. Can someone guide me?

thanks
Ananth

Answer (score 0):

So you want to cross-compile `libuv` (ie, compile it for a target architecture that is different from that of the computer you use to compile).

Since `libuv` uses `automake` for compilation, a good starting point is the [configure options page](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Cross_002dCompilation.html), in particular the `--host=` option.

```
./configure --host=<host>
```

Also, this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990021/how-to-determine-host-value-for-configure-when-using-cross-compiler) may be helpful.

Lastly, note you may have to configure your compiler so it supports cross-compiling (for example, see this [SO post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250696/cross-compile-for-arm) for `gcc` and Ubuntu).