# Correct iOS architecture names for autotools?

Tags: c++, ios, compiler-errors, autotools

What are the standard architecture names of mobile platforms, namely ARM-based, for autotools?

I've tried to build some C/C++ libs for iOS including `arm64`, `armv7`, and iOS simulators (`i386` and `x86_64`), but I always ended up having identical binaries for `arm64` and `x86_64-simulator`, which in turns fails the universal binary build by `lipo`. I've tried to set the `--build` and `--host` switches to one of the following pairs

- For arm64: --build=x86_64-apple-darwin`uname -r`, --host=arm64
- For x86_64-simulator: --build=x86_64-apple-darwin`uname -r`, --host=x86_64-apple-darwin`uname -r`

To my surprise, running the following script,

```sh
## Environments
ScriptDir="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"
cd - &> /dev/null

# Exit the build pass if any command returns a non-zero value
#set -o errexit


# Echo commands
set -x

DARWIN=darwin`uname -r`

MIN_SDK_VERSION=8.0

IPHONEOS_SYSROOT=`xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path`
IPHONESIMULATOR_SYSROOT=`xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path`

# Verbose clang output
#CLANG_VERBOSE="--verbose"

CC=/usr/bin/clang
CXX=/usr/bin/clang

SILENCED_WARNINGS="-Wno-unused-local-typedef -Wno-unused-function"
STDLIB=libc++

CFLAGS="${CLANG_VERBOSE} ${SILENCED_WARNINGS} -DNDEBUG -g -O0 -pipe -fPIC -fcxx-exceptions"
CXXFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -std=c++11 -stdlib=${STDLIB}"

LDFLAGS="-stdlib=${STDLIB}"
LIBS="-lc++ -lc++abi"

PROTOC=`which protoc`

SOURCE_DIR="$ScriptDir"

PREFIX="$ScriptDir"/_build
if [ -d ${PREFIX} ]
then
    rm -rf "${PREFIX}"
fi
mkdir -p "${PREFIX}/platform" &> /dev/null

## Functions

build_arch() {
  HOST=$1
  ARCH=$2
  PLATFORM_CFLAGS=$3
  PLATFORM_NAME=${ARCH}
  SYSROOT=${IPHONEOS_SYSROOT}

  ARCH_BITS=x86_64
  if [[ $ARCH==armv7 || $ARCH==armv7s ]]; then
    ARCH_BITS=i386
  fi

  CC="${CC}"
  CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} -arch ${ARCH} -isysroot ${SYSROOT} ${PLATFORM_CFLAGS}" \
  CXX="${CXX}" \
  CXXFLAGS="${CXXFLAGS} -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} -arch ${ARCH} -isysroot ${SYSROOT}" \
  LDFLAGS="-arch ${ARCH} -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} ${LDFLAGS}" \
  LIBS="${LIBS}" \
  ./configure \
    --without-gcc \
    --disable-ld-version-script \
    --build=x86_64-apple-${DARWIN} \
    --host=${HOST} \
    --with-protoc=${PROTOC} \
    --disable-shared \
    --prefix=${PREFIX} \
    --exec-prefix=${PREFIX}/platform/${PLATFORM_NAME}

  make -j8
  make install
}

build_simulator() {
  ARCH=$1
  PLATFORM_CFLAGS=$2
  HOST=${ARCH}-apple-${DARWIN}
  PLATFORM_NAME=${ARCH}-simulator
  SYSROOT=${IPHONESIMULATOR_SYSROOT}

  CC="${CC}" \
  CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -mios-simulator-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} -arch ${ARCH} -isysroot ${SYSROOT} ${PLATFORM_CFLAGS}" \
  CXX="${CXX}" \
  CXXFLAGS="${CXXFLAGS} -mios-simulator-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} -arch ${ARCH} -isysroot ${SYSROOT}" \
  LDFLAGS="-arch ${ARCH} -mios-simulator-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} ${LDFLAGS}" \
  LIBS="${LIBS}" \
  ./configure \
    --without-gcc \
    --disable-ld-version-script \
    --build=x86_64-apple-${DARWIN} \
    --host=${HOST} \
    --with-protoc=${PROTOC} \
    --disable-shared \
    --prefix=${PREFIX} \
    --exec-prefix=${PREFIX}/platform/${PLATFORM_NAME}

  make -j8
  make install
}


build_fat_lib() {
  OUT=${PREFIX}/universal
  mkdir -p ${OUT}

  PLATFORM_ROOT=${PREFIX}/platform
  LIPO=lipo

  LIB=libprotobuf.a
  ${LIPO} ${PLATFORM_ROOT}/arm64/lib/${LIB} \
          ${PLATFORM_ROOT}/x86_64-simulator/lib/${LIB} \
          -create \
          -output ${OUT}/${LIB}

  LIB_LITE=libprotobuf-lite.a
  ${LIPO} ${PLATFORM_ROOT}/arm64/lib/${LIB_LITE} \
          ${PLATFORM_ROOT}/x86_64-simulator/lib/${LIB_LITE} \
          -create \
          -output ${OUT}/${LIB_LITE}
}

## Build pass

cd ${SOURCE_DIR}

./autogen.sh

build_simulator x86_64 "-fembed-bitcode"

build_arch arm arm64 "-fembed-bitcode"

build_fat_lib

echo DONE!
```

, I end up getting complaints from lipo:

```sh
+ lipo /path/to/protobuf/_build/platform/arm64/lib/libprotobuf.a /path/to/protobuf/_build/platform/x86_64-simulator/lib/libprotobuf.a -create -output /path/to/protobuf/_build/universal/libprotobuf.a

fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: /path/to/protobuf/_build/platform/arm64/lib/libprotobuf.a and /path/to/protobuf/_build/platform/x86_64-simulator/lib/libprotobuf.a have the same architectures (x86_64) and can't be in the same fat output file
```

My first impression is that I'm misusing architecture names, and I don't know where to get the standard names. Is that it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine host value for configure when using cross compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990021/how-to-determine-host-value-for-configure-when-using-cross-compiler)

Comment: Note in particular the second answer to the proposed dupe target, which suggests running the `config.guess` script on an example of the wanted host machine.  If you can't or don't want to install Autoconf on that machine, then the script itself is available from GNU's Git server: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.guess.  Note that there is more than one ARM architecture.

Comment: However, I suspect your problem is different.  Since you are specifying compiler and arch-selection flags specifically, do make sure that these successfully produce cross binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself.

It turns out that the real problem is not a wrong arch triplet, but an inappropriate compiler executable assigned to CC/CXX. You gotta use

```
SDK="iphoneos"
export CC=$(xcrun --find --sdk "${SDK}" clang)
export CXX=$(xcrun --find --sdk "${SDK}" clang++)
export CPP=$(xcrun --find --sdk "${SDK}" cpp)
```

GOTCHA #1

`config.guess` as suggested by @JohnBolinger will always return

`x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0`

This leads to the wrong x86_64 build that I had before.

GOTCHA #2

Observe the Xcode build log and you may find `-target arm64-apple-ios13.1` as a Clang option, not to be confused with the autotool configure option `--target`. This one is useless either, unfortunately.

Comment: Just in case you are here as I was looking for an answer to compiling findutils-4.7.0 on the new Mac mini (M1) and got the same error of "Invalid configuration `arm64-apple-darwin20.2.0': machine `arm64-apple' not recognized"; I was able to resolve this with: --build=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu