# Error: C compiler cannot create executables when configuring Concorde TSP solver for Windows/Cygwin

Tags: r, windows, gcc, cygwin, configure

Trying to install Concorde TSP solver on Windows/Cygwin (ultimately for use in the R package TSP) and I'm running into errors when configuring the software. I've installed cygwin and followed the instructions [here](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde/DOC/README.html) to get Concorde set up in cygwin, but when I run the configure file, I get the error "C compiler cannot create executables".

```
$ CC="gcc" CFLAGS="-g -O3" ./configure --host=i686-pc-cygwin
loading cache ./config.cache
checking host system type... i686-pc-cygwin
checking for prespecified compiler options... yes
    Using default CC:       gcc
    Using default CPPFLAGS: -ansi -pedantic -Wall -W -Wtraditional -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs
    Using default CFLAGS:   -g -O3
    Using default LDFLAGS:
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler (gcc -g -O3 ) works... no
configure: error: installation or configuration problem: C compiler cannot create executables.
```

Here is the output from the config.log file as well:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

configure:593: checking host system type
configure:619: checking for prespecified compiler options
configure:716: checking for gcc
configure:829: checking whether the C compiler (gcc -g -O3 ) works
configure:845: gcc -o conftest -g -O3 -ansi -pedantic -Wall -W -Wtraditional -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs  conftest.c  1>&5
configure: failed program was:

#line 840 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"

main(){return(0);}
```

There's another question with essentially the same error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76328621/error-during-configuration-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables-concorde-tsp), but there doesn't seem to be any real solutions to the problem other than someone saying they didn't run into the issue on their system. Here's the output I get from running cygcheck on the packages that should be required to configure and compile Concorde.

```
$ cygcheck -c gcc-core make cygwin-devel
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
cygwin-devel         3.4.8-1        OK
gcc-core             11.4.0-1       OK
make                 4.4.1-2        OK
```

I've tried reinstalling cygwin and making sure I have the latest versions for all the packages I think I'd need in the cygwin setup, and it doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: What happens if you run `gcc` on the command line by itself?  Maybe it's not on the path, and your `CC` definition should give a full path to it.

Comment: @user2554330 I'm able to run gcc --help and gcc --version and get the expected output, so it seems to be finding gcc fine. But when I try to compile a simple "hello, world" test script with gcc test.c, I don't get a compiled exe or any errors.

Comment: I tried building Concorde TSP Solver with MSYS2+MinGW-w64 (instead of cygwin), and that builds just fine.

Comment: @BrechtSanders I was finally able to get it to configure with clang instead of gcc, but then I couldn’t compile because it couldn’t find my QSopt library, even though I tried everything I could to make sure it was on the path and specified in the configure options. I might have to try building in another environment because I’ve had nothing but problems with cygwin. Thanks for the tip.